# it's good for your dime

Tags: slang, north-american-english, lyrics, songs

I was listening to [Moonshine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p9zUol0oCpY) a [Kill the Vultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_the_Vultures) tune.

I'm not sure about the meaning of:

> it's good for your dime

Does he mean it is cheap?

complete sentence:

> I got moonshine
>
> Drink it all the time
>
> Goes down rough but it's good for your dime

Comment: Yes - or more accurately, it's good value for the cheap expense. From a quick Google search, it looks like it's an idiomatic USA expression - not very common, but it's clearly not just something Kill the Vultures has made up. An ideal opportunity for an EL&U user to earn some good points for a well-researched answer (especially with some etymology) - this is the kind of question we love!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, **it implies that moonshine is inexpensive or cost-effective**.

That last sentence, "*Goes down rough but it's good for your dime*" is saying that it may be difficult to drink but that is relative to the price you've paid for it.  In contrast, a more refined liquor may be considered smooth (i.e., easier to drink) but it would be hard on your dime (i.e., costs more).

Nb. For non-North-American readers, a "dime" is a coin of currency in USA and Canada, and it's often used to refer to money in general.

Comment: The implication is also that you are getting more units of alcohol per mouthful than from other drinks

Comment: `hard on your dime`  +1!

Answer (score 1):

In the "old days" (basically before World War II), a "dime" was a basic unit of American currency that was enough to buy a poor person's item like a loaf of bread, or a shot of (cheap) whiskey. A song popular in those depressed days was ["Brother can you spare a dime?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brother,_Can_You_Spare_a_Dime%3F)

Because of inflation, that is no longer true; what used to be known as a "dime" store is now a "dollar" store or ["99 cent store"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/99_Cents_Only_Stores).

But the usage stuck in songs and poetry, and "good for your dime," means good for the "cheapest brand." Given its low cost, you can't reasonably expect better than "goes down rough" (but otherwise good).